# How can I ask for external file access permission in Android Q?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-10.0

Heard **Android Q** introduced a new security feature called **“Scoped Storage”** which restricts access files in external storage. My problem is I have to save a text document to a user specified location from the App. Is this requires any kind of permission rather than `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in Q devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is I have to save a text document to a user specified location from the App

Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to specify the location. You can use use a `ContentResolver` and its `openOutputStream()` method to get an `OutputStream` for the `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`. You can then write your text to that `OutputStream`.

> Is this requires any kind of permission rather than READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Q devices?

`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` requires no permissions and works back to Android 4.4.

Alternatively, you can write your file to a directory identified by `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`. This portion of external storage is visible to the user on Android Q and requires no additional permissions.

Or, if you keep your `targetSdkVersion` to 28 or lower, you can use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and write where you want, as you did on Android 9.0+. However, bear in mind that this approach will stop working with Android R and when you raise your `targetSdkVersion` past 28 (e.g., to comply with 2020's Play Store requirements). So, using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, or perhaps `getExternalFilesDir()`, is the better long-term answer.

Comment: Can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63543414/rename-file-of-the-external-storage-which-is-created-by-app-in-android-10-worki